# How to dynamically include file with variable in EJS version 2?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, ejs

Recently, I was using EJS(version - 0.8.4) that was working fine with following updation in File: node_modules/lib/ejs.js at line ~ 155 :

Old code :

```
 if (0 == js.trim().indexOf('include')) {
var name = js.trim().slice(7).trim();
if (!filename) throw new Error('filename option is required for includes');
var path = resolveInclude(name, filename);
include = read(path, 'utf8');
include = exports.parse(include, { filename: path, _with: false, open: open, close: close, compileDebug: compileDebug });
buf.push("' + (function(){" + include + "})() + '");
js = '';  }
```

To this code :

```
if (0 == js.trim().indexOf('include')) {
var name = js.trim().slice(7).trim();
if (!filename) throw new Error('filename option is required for includes');
// If it is not path, but variable name (Added)
if(options[name])
     var path = resolveInclude(options[name], filename);
else
     var path = resolveInclude(name, filename);
include = read(path, 'utf8');
include = exports.parse(include, options); // Added transfer whole options
buf.push("' + (function(){" + include + "})() + '");
js = '';  }
```

In ejs file simple write :

```
<%- include variable%> in place of <%- include header.ejs %>
```

where varibale = header or some other include filepath.

But it not working with EJS (version : 2.3.4), What should I do to resolve this because if it won't resolve, I ll be in big trouble.

One more thing to ask : Is there any alternate for ejs.filter in this updated version(2.3.4)?

Comment: Can anyone please suggest... thanks

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `<%- include variable%>` 
try using <%- include (variable) %> it takes inside value as variable.

if u skip brackets it will interpret as string "variable" and  search for that ejs file.